# Unicorn workers timeout after "zero downtime" deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I'm running a Rails 3.2.21 app and deploy to a Ubuntu 12.04.5 box using capistrano (nginx and unicorn).

I have my app set for a zero-downtime deploy (at least I *thought*), with my config files looking more or less like [these](http://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2014/03/08/zero-downtime-deployment-with-unicorn-and-capistrano/).

**Here's the problem:** When the deploy is nearly done and it restarts unicorn, when I watch my unicorn.log I see it fire up the new workers, reap the old ones... but then my app just hangs for 2-3 minutes. Any request to the app at this point hits the timeout window (which I set to 40 seconds) and returns my app's 500 error page.

Here is the first part of the output from **unicorn.log** as unicorn is restarting (I have 5 unicorn workers):

```
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:57.022492 #14347]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:57.844273 #15378]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:57.944080 #15381]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:58.089655 #15390]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:58.230554 #14541]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15551 exit 0> worker=4
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:58.231455 #14541]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 3644 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:58.249110 #15393]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:06:58.650007 #15396]  INFO -- : worker=4 ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:07:01.246981 #14541]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 32645 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2015-04-21T23:07:01.561786 #14541]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15534 exit 0> worker=2
I, [2015-04-21T23:07:06.657913 #14541]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16821 exit 0> worker=3
I, [2015-04-21T23:07:06.658325 #14541]  INFO -- : master complete
```

Afterwards, as the app hangs for those 2-3 minutes, here is what's happening:

```
E, [2015-04-21T23:07:38.069635 #14347] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:15378 timeout (41s > 40s), killing
E, [2015-04-21T23:07:38.243005 #14347] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15378 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
E, [2015-04-21T23:07:39.647717 #14347] ERROR -- : worker=3 PID:15393 timeout (41s > 40s), killing
E, [2015-04-21T23:07:39.890543 #14347] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 15393 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=3
I, [2015-04-21T23:07:40.727755 #16002]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2015-04-21T23:07:43.212395 #16022]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
E, [2015-04-21T23:08:24.511967 #14347] ERROR -- : worker=3 PID:16022 timeout (41s > 40s), killing
E, [2015-04-21T23:08:24.718512 #14347] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 16022 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=3
I, [2015-04-21T23:08:28.010429 #16234]  INFO -- : worker=3 ready
```

Eventually, after 2 or 3 minutes, the app starts being responsive again, but everything is more sluggish. You can see this very clearly in New Relic (the horizontal line marks the deploy, and the light blue area indicates Ruby):

[image: New Relic graph during and after deploy]

I have an identical staging server, and I cannot replicate the issue in staging... granted, staging is under no load (I'm the only person trying to make page requests).

Here is my **config/unicorn.rb** file:

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/myawesomeapp/current"
working_directory root

pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

shared_path = "/home/deployer/apps/myawesomeapp/shared"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.myawesomeapp.sock"
worker_processes 5
timeout 40

preload_app true

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{root}/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  old_pid = "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH

    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

And just to paint a complete picture, in my capistrano **deploy.rb**, the unicorn restart task looks like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart, roles: :app, except: { no_release: true } do
    run "kill -s USR2 `cat #{release_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`"
  end
end
```

Any ideas why the unicorn workers timeout right after the deploy? I thought the point of a zero-downtime was to keep the old ones around until the new ones are spun up and ready to serve?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I did another deploy, and this time kept an eye on **production.log** to see what was going on there. The only suspicious thing was the following lines, which were mixed in with normal requests:

```
Dalli/SASL authenticating as 7510de
Dalli/SASL: 7510de
Dalli/SASL authenticating as 7510de
Dalli/SASL: 7510de
Dalli/SASL authenticating as 7510de
Dalli/SASL: 7510de
```

**UPDATE #2**

As suggested by some of the answers below, I changed the `before_fork` block to add `sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU` so the workers would be incrementally killed off.

Same result, *terribly* slow deploy, with the same spike I illustrated in the graph above. Just for context, out of my 5 worker processes, the first 4 sent a TTOU signal, and the 5th sent QUIT. Still, does not seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Are you precompiling assets during the deploy or is it compiling all of them when you hit the app for the first time?

Comment: @infused It appears I am precompiling them during the deploy. I see a line in the deploy output that says `executing "cd -- /home/deployer/apps/myawesomeapp/releases/20150422035053 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"` which is a command that takes around 30 seconds to finish.

Comment: Op, did you manage to solve this issue? I am encountering the same with my prodution setup

Comment: @GaneshHegde Yeah, I did. It was a while ago, and while I don't remember exactly if I had to make any major config changes, the memory on my server had a lot to do with it. I moved to a different host and increased server memory. Also, if I recall correctly, upgrading to ruby 2 greatly impacted memory management and speed. I'm still on Rails 3.2, but now I have very fast, zero downtime deploys. 
You could test this by decreasing your Unicorn workers one at a time then deploying, to see if your deploys start getting faster. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar problem recently while trying to set up Rails/Nginx/Unicorn on Digital Ocean. I was able to get zero-downtime deploys to work after tweaking a few things. Here are a few things to try:

1. Reduce the number of worker process.
2. Increase the memory of your server. I was getting timeouts on the 512MB RAM droplet. Seemed to fix the issue when I increased it to 1GB.
3. Use the "capistrano3-unicorn" gem.
4. If preload_app true, use restart (USR2). If false, use reload (HUP).
5. Ensure "tmp/pids" is in the set as a linked_dirs in deploy.rb.
6. Use `px aux | grep unicorn` to make sure the old processes are being removed.
7. Use `kill [pid]` to manually stop any unicorn processes still running.

Here's my unicorn config for reference:

```
working_directory '/var/www/yourapp/current'
pid '/var/www/yourapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid'
stderr_path '/var/www/yourapp/log/unicorn.log'
stdout_path '/var/www/yourapp/log/unicorn.log'
listen '/tmp/unicorn.yourapp.sock'
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  old_pid = "/var/www/yourapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
  if old_pid != server.pid
    begin
    sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
    Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end
```

deploy.rb

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'yourapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/yourapp.git'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/yourapp'
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/application.yml')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :info
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.3'

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    #invoke 'unicorn:reload'
    invoke 'unicorn:restart'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the troubleshooting steps. A few thoughts:

**1 & 2)** Reduce the number of worker processes doesn't seem to be necessary, since my 5 Unicorn workers are taking up 3GB out of the 8GB I have available on the server.
**3)** I'm using Capistrano 2.15.4
**4)** Why? I've read this is a bad idea, and that preload_app true is best
**5)** Don't quite understand this one
**6)** I can confirm they are being removed
**7)** No need

Comment: **4)** Disregard that step. Just tested it with preload_app true and it works as well. **5)** In my setup, the tmp/pids in current is symlinked to tmp/pids in shared where the old unicorn pid is stored. **other)** Your set up seems correct, I'm not sure why it's not working. This is the command that gets run at the end of my deploy `/usr/bin/env kill -s USR2 \`cat /var/www/yourapp/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid\``

Comment: This is the command that gets run for my unicorn restart: `kill -s USR2 `cat /home/deployer/apps/myapp/releases/20150504213742/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid``  Looks like it's using the **release path**, and not the **current path**. Also, I don't think it's running the `kill -s USR2` from `/usr/bin/env` ... wonder what difference that makes?

Answer (score 1):

Are you vendoring unicorn and having cap run a bundle install on deploy? If so this could be an executable issue.

When you do a Capistrano deploy, cap creates a new release directory for your revision and moves the `current` symlink to point to the new release. If you haven't told the running unicorn to gracefully update the path to its executable, it should work if you add this line:

`Unicorn::HttpServer::START_CTX[0] = ::File.join(ENV['GEM_HOME'].gsub(/releases\/[^\/]+/, "current"),'bin','unicorn')`

You can find some more information [here](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Sandbox.html). I think the before_fork block you have looks good, but I would add the `sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU` line from [@travisluong's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1909628/travisluong) answer as well; that will incrementally kill off the workers as the new ones spawn.

I would not remove `preload_app true`, incidentally, as it greatly improves worker spawn time.

Comment: Can you give more details on "vendoring unicorn and having cap run a bundle install on deploy"? How can I confirm if I'm doing this? Also, where would I add the line `Unicorn::HttpServer::START_CTX[0] ...`?

Comment: You should add the Unicorn::HttpServer line at the top of the config.